# Makeindex and see subentry

Tags: xetex, indexing

In the following nearly-MWE I get an index-entry for `simple, example` and one for `ex, see example`, but I don't get one for `example, see simple, example`.

How can I get an indexentry like the last one?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

Here it is a simple example\index{simple!example}

\index{example|see{simple!example}}
\index{ex|see{example}}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

compile with

```
xelatex mwe.tex
makeindex mwe.idx
xelatex mwe.tex
```

Exact wording like described does not matter, important is that I can have a `see` to a sub- or sub-sub-entry instead of a toplevel one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Blame myself, just stumbled upon a solution…

Instead of writing the see-clause as you write the actual index, you have to write the see-clause as you want to see it in the document.

So instead of writing `\index{example|see{simple!example}}`, you have to write `\index{example|see{simple, example}}`.

So the MWE would be:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

Here it is a simple example\index{simple!example}

\index{example|see{simple, example}}
\index{ex|see{example}}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: MakeIndex does nothing with the argument to `see`, apart packing it as the argument to `\see` in the `.ind` file.